# mIoU for multi-class

Tags: deep-learning, metrics, semantic-segmentation

I would like to understand how mIoU is calculated for multi-class classification. The formula for each class is

[IoU formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yZIR.png)

and then the average is done over the classes to get the mIoU. However, I don't understand what happens for the classes that are not represented. The formula becomes a division by 0, so I ignore them and the average is only computed for the classes represented.

The problem is that when a prediction is wrong, the accuracy is really lowered. It adds another class to make the average. For instance : in semantic segmentation the ground-truth of an image is made of 4 classes (0,1,2,3) and 6 classes are represented over the dataset. The prediction is also made of 4 classes (0,1,4,5) but all the items classified in 2 and 3 (in the ground-truth) are classified in 4 and 5 (in the prediction). In this case should we calculate the mIoU over 6 classes ? Even if 4 classes are totally wrong and there respective IoU is 0 ? So the problem is that if just one pixel is predicted in a class that is not in the ground_truth, we have to divide by a higher denominator and it lows a lot the score.

Is it the correct way to compute the mIoU for multi-class (and the semantic segmentation) ?

Answer (score 2):

What's really wrong is this answer:

```py
classwise_IOU = i/u # tensor of size (num_classes)
mIOU = i.sum()/u.sum() # mean IOU, taking (i/u).mean() is wrong
```

`(i/u).mean()`

is correct!
Even in the code that pu239 linked you can find

```py
iou_class = intersection_meter.sum / (union_meter.sum + 1e-10)
mIoU = np.mean(iou_class)
```

Comment: The mIOU is described as the mean IOU by each class, and using `(i/u).mean()` gave me results like other libraries, such as evaluate from _hugging_face_. I think that is correct, too!

Comment: Yes, (i/u).mean() is the standard procedure in all recent work I know.
But there is no official definition, see [this discussion](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/104746/is-there-an-official-procedure-to-compute-miou)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calculating the miou of each image and then calculate the "mean" miou over all the images, I calculate the miou as one big image. If a class is not in the image and is not predicited, I set there respective iou equal to 1.

From scratch :

```
def miou(gt,pred,nbr_mask):
    intersection = np.zeros(nbr_mask) # int = (A and B)
    den = np.zeros(nbr_mask) # den = A + B = (A or B) + (A and B)
    for i in range(len(gt)):
        for j in range(height):
            for k in range(width):
                if pred[i][j][k]==gt[i][j][k]:
                    intersection[gt[i][j][k]]+=1
                den[pred[i][j][k]] += 1
                den[gt[i][j][k]] += 1
    mIoU = 0
    for i in range(nbr_mask):
        if den[i]!=0:
            mIoU+=intersection[i]/(den[i]-intersection[i])
        else:
            mIoU+=1
    mIoU=mIoU/nbr_mask
    return mIoU
```

With `gt` the array of ground truth labels and `pred` the prediction of theassociated images (have to correspond in the array and be the same size).

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the previous answer, this is a great fast and efficient pytorch GPU implementation of calculating the mIOU and classswise IOU for a batch of size `(N, H, W)` (both pred mask and labels), taken from the NeurIPS 2021 paper ["Few-Shot Segmentation via Cycle-Consistent Transformer"](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2021/file/b8b12f949378552c21f28deff8ba8eb6-Paper.pdf), github repo available [here](https://github.com/YanFangCS/CyCTR-Pytorch).

```py
def intersectionAndUnionGPU(output, target, K, ignore_index=255):
    # 'K' classes, output and target sizes are N or N * L or N * H * W, each value in range 0 to K - 1.
    assert (output.dim() in [1, 2, 3])
    assert output.shape == target.shape
    output = output.view(-1)
    target = target.view(-1)
    output[target == ignore_index] = ignore_index
    intersection = output[output == target]
    area_intersection = torch.histc(intersection, bins=K, min=0, max=K-1)
    area_output = torch.histc(output, bins=K, min=0, max=K-1)
    area_target = torch.histc(target, bins=K, min=0, max=K-1)
    area_union = area_output + area_target - area_intersection
    return area_intersection, area_union, area_target
```

Example usage:

```py
output = torch.rand(4, 5, 224, 224) # model output; batch size=4; channels=5, H,W=224
preds = F.softmax(output, dim=1).argmax(dim=1) # (4, 224, 224)
labels = torch.randint(0,5, (4, 224, 224))

i, u, _ = intersectionAndUnionGPU(preds, labels, 5) # 5 is num_classes

classwise_IOU = i/u # tensor of size (num_classes) 
mIOU = (i/u).mean() # mean IOU, taking (i/u).mean() is wrong
```

Hope this helps everyone!

(A non-GPU implementation is available as well in the repo!)

Edit (1/11/23): Changed `i.sum()/u.sum()` to `(i/u).mean()` in the example usage based on Jonas' answer (the function did not change). I did some digging around, and although I was never able to find a concrete definition of mIoU by a trusted source, it seems the `huggingface` library has implemented it that way, based on `mmsegmentation`'s implementation ([huggingface PR](https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/pull/3745)). Note that `mmsegmentation`'s implementation does not return the mean IoU even when asked for; rather, it returns the array/tensor of IoUs (`i/u`). Only the `huggingface` PR uses a `np.nanmean` on top of this.
Although I do see now why this should be the way to do it.